# How can I stick a message in only once in jgrowl?

Tags: jquery, jgrowl

Is there a way to stick(y) a message in the collection only one time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question, according to [the examples](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html), a message will be sticky if you set the flag, and when you dismiss it, it doesn't show up again...

Do you have some global pool of messages that you want each user to see, that you show on each page, but not show again if he hides the message?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the stick attributes sticks the notification to the window. If you want unique notifications per browser instance this is not a feature of jGrowl and you will need to track it yourself. You can do this by using the data attribute of the container, creating a map and checking it in the beforeOpen callback and returning false if it exists in your map. If you set the callback in your defaults it will apply to all messages created.